# Generate three dimensional arrays using mvnrnd in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I need to generate a three dimensional matrix `B` in Matlab using the command `mvnrnd`. In particular, let

`mu=[0 0; -1 -3; 0 4; 2 4; 8 1]`

and

`sigma=repmat(1/(3^2)*eye(2),[1,1,5])`

If I use the command

`B= mvnrnd(mu,sigma)`

I get a matrix `5x2` in which each row `i` is sampled from `N(mu(i,:), sigma(:,:,i))`. 
Instead, I want `B` to be `5x2xr`, i.e. each row `i`is sampled from `N(mu(i,:), sigma(:,:,i))` `r` times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows:

1. Repeat `mu` along 1st dimension and `sigma` along 3rd dimension by a factor of `r` and feed them to `mvnrnd`. That way you get the desired number of samples, but the `r` matrices are stacked along 1st dimension, instead of along 3rd dimension as desired.
2. Then play with dimensions to put into desired form.

Code:

```
B = mvnrnd(repmat(mu, [r 1]), repmat(sigma, [1 1 r])); %// step 1
B = permute(reshape(B.', size(mu,2), size(mu,1), r), [2 1 3]);  %'// step 2
```